# How to Test cakephp parseExtension?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, components, cakephp-2.3

I setup the `parseExtension` for json in my cakephp 2.3.0. No errors are display. It works?

How can I test is?

In RoR ist ist very easy to test via

```
https://mydomain.de/view/4.json
```

How does it run on cakephp?

My View-Action is this.

```
 public function view($id = null) {
            if (!$this->Atla->exists($id)) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid atla'));
            }
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Atla.' . $this->Atla->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->set('atla', $this->Atla->find('first', $options));

            $this->Atla->id = $id;
            $result = $this->Atla->read();
            $this->response->type('json');
            $this->response->body(json_encode($result));
            return $this->response;   
            $this->set(compact('atlas'));

    }
```

Why i always get an json-request?

Comment: If i type this into my browser i get the Error `{"code":500,"url":"\/Atlas\/view\/2.json","name":"View file &quot;\/usr\/local\/www\/cakephp\/app\/View\/Atlas\/json\/view.ctp&quot; is missing."}`

Comment: Then it seems to be working! All you'll have to do is create the view `app/View/Atlas/json/view.ctp` which is the view that is being used for .json requests. Requests *without* .json will use `app/View/Atlas/view.ctp` :) There's more information on creating/using JSON and XML views here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: is this an normal (c&p) view-file or should it be empty?

Comment: I put an explanation in an answer below, as comments don't offer much options to format code and keep it readable. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [_serialize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key) key cakephp can automatically create json and xml views for you.  I typically use the following to create json or xml views:

```
public function view() {
  // data I want to display
  $record1 = $this->ModelName->find('first', ...);
  $this->set('record1', $record1);

  $record2 = $this->ModelName->find('first', ...);
  $this->set('record2', $record2);


  // option 1: serialize the hard way 
  $this->set('_serialize', array('record1', 'record2'));

  // option 2: serialize the easy way
  $this->set('_serialize', array_keys($this->viewVars));
}
```

PS: the code after your `return` statement will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have create the view

app/View/Atlas/json/view.ctp

which is the view that is being used for .json requests.
Requests *without* .json will use the regular view file:

```
app/View/Atlas/view.ctp
```

There's more information on creating/using JSON and XML views here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files

From that page the view.ctp may contain something like;

```
// View code - app/View/Posts/json/index.ctp
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
    unset($post['Post']['generated_html']);
}
echo json_encode(compact('posts', 'comments'));
```

However, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you will only use the 'Atlas/view' action for JSON responses, and won't be using HTML at all, sometimes you can get away with generating the response-body inside your Controller. Not very much 'in line' with MVC conventions, but it saves you from creating a view that does nothing more than `echo json_encode($data);` ;)

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->MyModel->id = $id;
    $result = $this->MyModel->read();

    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->body(json_encode($result));

    //Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

If you *do* want to use both 'HTML' and 'JSON', depending on the request (with/without .json extension), you should have *two* view files; 1 for JSON and 1 for HTML;

```
// This view will be used for your JSON requests
app/View/Atlas/json/view.ctp

// This view will be used for non-JSON (html) requests:
app/View/Atlas/view.ctp
```

In the json-view, output the data using json_encode(.....);
In the 'normal'/html view, just output normal data

In your controller, set the data as normal

```
public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Atla->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Atla->exists()) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid atla'));
        }
        $this->set('atla', $this->Atla->read());

}
```

Comment: I alwas get the json request... no html :-( I edit my question with view controller.

Comment: That is, because in your code you're always returning a JSON response. If you want to use *both* HTML or JSON, you should not return the response in your controller, but create two separate view-files; I'll update my anser

Comment: The json-view is your way. This runs fine Thanks
The html-view is baked. But give me an html with styles

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>
  CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:
  Atlas </title>
 <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css" /></head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="header">
   <h1><a href="http://cakephp.org">CakePHP: the rapid development php framework</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">`

Comment: The styles you see are the 'layout' that is used. Views are rendered in a layout. The default layout can be found here `app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`. But for this kind of questions, please look in the documentation,